# What is a better WiFi 6 setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have recently upgraded my router to the ASUS ZenWifi AX and am wondering what is a better setup. The fiber optics (1Gbps) access point and the modem are located on a wall two rooms away from the office so a direct connection is not feasible. The first router is located in the living room, as far away from the modem as possible. The second unit I have tested either in the kitchen (i.e. between the living room and the office) or the office. When the second unit is located in the kitchen I can measure a speed close to 500 Mbps by connecting my laptop to the router via ethernet. Speeds on the first router range between 500 to 600 Mbps so it appears that the single wall separating both units isn't degrading the signal too much. However, when I set the second unit in the office and connect my PC to the router I see significant speed decrement maxing out at 250Mbps (but more often at 200 Mbps). If I leave the router in the kitchen and connect wirelessly my maximum speed is lowered further to about 130Mbps.

I am currently considering getting a WiFi 6 capable antenna and leaving the second unit in the kitchen. What is in your opinion the preferred setup? Getting the antenna? Leaving the router in my office?

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else I am answering my question. Using the antenna (also WIFI 6 standard) more than doubled the maximum speed I was able to achieve. The best performing setup is router 1 in the living room, router 2 in the kitchen and wireless connection to the office PC.